# Java:Click on every JButton from container

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, containers

I have a container that has only JButtons in it and I want to click on all the buttons from code so that I don't click on them manually from the interface, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually call a method called doClick() to do this

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick()

Basically, you should be able to do something like:

```
myButton.doClick()
```

and if you have an ActionListener attached to the button it will act as if the user clicked the button.

Comment: and how can i get the button from the container? so that i can call the doClick() on it?

Comment: @guNNer2bad If you don't have a list of the buttons, you will need to use the getComponents method. You will to check the instance of each component to check if its a JButton or not

Answer (score 0):

You can call clickListener method explicitly. Or write a method like clickListener and call it.